# Cannot bind app-route with iron-selector and iron-pages

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am freaking upset with my bug. `<app-route>` is working but that FREAKING `<iron-pages>` CANNOT APPLY `class="iron-selected"` TO ANY OF IT'S CHILD!!!

index.html

```
<app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path></app-location>

<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" data="{{data}}" tail="{{tail}}"></app-route>

<iron-selector selected="[[data.page]]" attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="Question">
  <a name="Questions" href="#/Questions">
    <paper-button raised id="askbutton" onclick="submitquestion()">Ask</paper-button>
  </a>
<iron-selector>

<iron-pages role="main" id="view-selector" selected="[[data.page]]" attr-for-selected="name">

  <q-card id="my-database-ref-id" route="{{route}}" name="Questions">

  <answer-panel name="Question" route="{{tail}}" ></answer-panel>

</iron-pages>
```

q-card.html

```
<paper-card elevation=1 class="qcardclass" id="qcard">
  <div class="cui">

  </div>
  <div class="q">
    <h1 id="q" class="q">{{QuestionData.qis}}<!--<Questioninshort-Data></Questioninshort-Data>--></h1>
  </div>

  <iron-selector selected="{{data.page}}"
                  attr-for-selected="name">

    <a name="Question" href="#/Question/{{QuestionData.Key}}">

    <paper-icon-button name="Question" icon="arrow-forward" align="right" class="aar" ></paper-icon-button>

    </a>

    </iron-selector>

</paper-card>
```

answer-panel.html

```
<!-- <app-location route="{{route}}" use-hash-as-path ></app-location> -->

<!-- <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:question_id" data="{{subrouteData}}"></app-route> -->
      <iron-selector selected="{{data.page}}"
                  attr-for-selected="name"> -->

  <a name="Questions" href="#/Questions">

  <paper-icon-button icon="clear" align="right" class="close" onclick="answerformclose()"></paper-icon-button>

  </a>

  </iron-selector>
```

Idk where the mistake is happening,if it is binding problem or any deeper problem, Please help me.

Comment: Why you have same name as  name="Questions" for both pages ? recheck your route and name for each pages

Comment: i changed that but it still don't works @VinodLouis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. I just moved my whole app from index.html to a custom element.